# How do I understand this expression in an Excel IF statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators

I have downloaded an excel sheet with some formulas for computing time dependent variables. 
The sheet works perfectly fine, by the way, and does its job. I am trying to deduce the mathematics of the whole model by understanding the formulas in it. One of the formulas reads as the following:

`=IF((($B$18>$B$19)*($B$8>=$B$19))+(($B$18<$B$19)*($B$8<=$B$19)),AG30+((F30*$K$22)/($B$13)),$H$230)`

On searching a bit on the internet, I find that usually in excel IF statements are written in the following format:

`=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

That would imply that the logical test in this case is:

`(($B$18>$B$19)*($B$8>=$B$19))+(($B$18<$B$19)*($B$8<=$B$19))`

This expression has four instances where >, >=, <, <= are being used and they're connected by + and * arithmetic operators. I am confused about what kind of logical statement this is. Do the * and + symbols stand for operators like AND and OR, respectively, or do they stand for something else?

Any help and/or pointers are appreciated :)

Comment: They stand for the expected mathematical operators (multiple and add). You should test each individual component of the equation. So in one cell, enter `B18>B19`. You will see that this returns a `TRUE/FALSE` response. Then consider what happens when you multiple and add these Boolean responses. Continue breaking each part out until you start to understand how it fits into the whole. The first part of the equation can only return the values `0, 1, or 2`

Comment: but how can boolean values be added or multiplied. By your explanation, the logical statements would mean for example:
(true * true) + (false * false)

Comment: Try values in the 3 cells... either B8 & B18 have to be greater than B19 or less than... And you should know that "true" = 1 and "False" = 0

Comment: @AbhishekSKhetan - have you tried to do this? If you sub in your equation with actual booleans, you will find that the sample equation you provided returns 1.  `TRUE * TRUE = 1` and `TRUE + TRUE = 2` and `TRUE * FALSE = 0`

Comment: "And you should know that "true" = 1 and "False" = 0". Thanks! now I get it.

Comment: Update to my first comment, your equation can only return `1 or 0` since only one side of your addition equation can be true at the same time. As stated above, `1 = TRUE` and `0 = FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Someone used mathematical operators instead of logical ones, here is what that formula says:

"If either B18 is greater than B19 or B8 is greater than or equal to B19 and either B18 is less than B19, or B8 is greater than or equal to B19, then"
...(value if true),(value if false)

An easier formula to grasp IMO is this one:

`=IF(OR(AND(B18>B19,B8>=B19),AND(B18<B19,B8<=B19)),AG30+((F30*$K$22)/($B$13)),$H$230)`

Answer (score 0):

In Formula Tab, excel have Formula validation
With this function you can simulation step by step your cell formula.
Let try it!